# Logging to different directories using log4j based on context

Tags: java, log4j

I have a multi threaded application in which I want to log to different directories based on the context from where the log message was generated.

I don't want or need a single directory for each thread. In my case I have multiple threads that belong to the same context and should share the same log directory. The context is identified by a named object.

I did find multiple solutions explaining how to separate your log into multiple files using the LogLevel, Thread name and system variables.

In fact I already use a system variable to write to different directories based on the application that is currently running (multiple applications share this config). Here it is:

```
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>    
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${sys:logfiledir}/out.log" filePattern="${sys:logfiledir}/out-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%-5p %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}{GMT+0} UTC %C:%L - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
                <Delete basePath="${sys:logfiledir}" >
                    <IfLastModified age="10d" />
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
        <Console name="Console">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%-5p %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}{GMT+0} UTC %C:%L - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="de" level="${sys:loglevel}" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
            <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

It would be great if I could pass a string parameter into the `LogManager.getLogger()` function that would be used to determine the subdirectory in which to log into. But for what I can tell that is not an option.

If all fails I guess I could give up on the XML configuration and build multiple appenders and loggers programatically based on the contexts I have.

Comment: Log4j is end-of-life and obsolete.  You should not be writing code to use it.

Comment: Version 1.x of Log4j reached EOL. This configuration file uses the 2.x syntax.